# sum all rows pairwise in two data frames and save to matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a data frame df1 and a data frame df 2

```
df1

colA colB ...
30    2   ...
3     100 ...
15    9   ...
..    ..  ...

df2

colA colB ...
10    200 ...
0     10  ...
55    1   ...
..    ..  ...
```

I would like to sum all the rows in colA of df1 with colA in df2 and so on for the rest of the columns

Output:

```
df3

colA colB
40    202
3     110
70    10
```

I would like to fill up the values to a matrix
I have written something like this:

```
results <- matrix(NA, ncol=ncol(df1), nrow=nrow(df1))
rownames(results) <- rownames(df1)
colnames(results) <- colnames(df1)

for (i in seq(df1)) {
  tempCol1 <- df1[, i]
  for (row in rownames(results))
    for (j in seq(results)){
      results[row,j]<-sum(df1[row, tempCol1 ], 
                          df2[row, tempCol1 ])
}}
```

it give this error:

> Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, row, j, value = sum(a[row, tempCol1], b[row,
> tempCol1])) :    subscript out of bounds

Comment: Try `results <- df1 + df2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it to a matrix and add up them.

Directly add two `data.frame` also works as well.

```
df1 = data.frame(colA = c(30, 3, 15), colB = c(2, 100, 9))
df2 = data.frame(colA = c(10, 0, 55), colB = c(200, 10, 1))
as.matrix(df1)+ as.matrix(df2)
df1+df2

> as.matrix(df1)+ as.matrix(df2)
     colA colB
[1,]   40  202
[2,]    3  110
[3,]   70   10

> df1+df2
  colA colB
1   40  202
2    3  110
3   70   10
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use a `for loop` for this problem. Simply add them up:

```
m = as.matrix(df1 + df2)
```

Comment: sure...but I wanted to do that by writing a loop because besides sum I can as well apply another formula

Comment: for (i in colnames(df1)) {
  tempCol1 <- print(i)
  for (row in rownames(results))
    results[row,tempCol1]<-sum(df1[row, tempCol1 ], # Grab values using row and
                          df2[row, tempCol1 ])
}

Comment: this worked in a loop

Answer (score 0):

We can do a regular + which will preserve the matrix format and does the elementwise summation,  below snippet will get the job done

```
df1 <- data.frame (
  col1 = c(30, 3, 15),
  col2 = c(2, 100, 19)
)

df2 <- data.frame (
  col1 = c(30, 3, 15),
  col2 = c(2, 100, 19)
)

my_mat1 <- as.matrix(df1)
my_mat2 <- as.matrix(df2)

result = my_mat1 + my_mat2;
```